# Make a sad unicorn happy!

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins, unicorns

I am here to propose that a % of all unicoin's earned for the rest of the day count towards a donation to "Make a sad unicorn happy!" the group prevents any and all unhappy unicorns from becoming specialty in several different restaurants around the world where people specifically seek for unicorns as well as other cruelties such as skinning and others.

I've been able to see first hand what kind of cruelty they do such as:

[image: Unicorns on a stick]
*Unicorns on a stick*

[image: Canned unicorn meat]
*Canned unicorn meat*

[image: unicorn pet disguise]
*unicorn pet disguise*

And several other cruelties.

I hope StackOverflow will join the cause and if possible add a donation counter below the unicoin's widget...

## If you support this act, post an answer with what sort of cruelty against unicorns have you seen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very sad that my spell checker doesn't recognize the word "Unicoin".